# glass timeline update happening but both the old and the updated cards are visible

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

After a timeline card is updated by the Glassware, is it possible to have only the updated timeline card visible on Glass. Currently, I can see the old timeline card as well as updated timeline card on Glass, but obviously w/ differnt timestamp.

Here's more explanation w/ code:-
There are two java classes, NewUserBootstrapper and NotifyServlet. The NewUserBootstrapper takes care of bootstrapping that includes authentication, inserting contact and inserting subscription. This is the code for inserting a timeline item as part of bootstrapping.

```
// Send a timeline item
TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
timelineItem.setText("Hello");
timelineItem.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));
TimelineItem insertedItem = MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, timelineItem);
```

Now in the NotifyServlet, after the Service is notified of changes to the timeline as part of "take a note" voice command, the NotifyServlet tries to update the text of the same timeline item.

```
  if (notification.getCollection().equals("timeline")) {
     // Get the impacted timeline item
     TimelineItem timelineItem =  
     mirrorClient.timeline().get(notification.getItemId()).execute();

 //Take a note
 if (notification.getUserActions().contains(new UserAction().setType("LAUNCH")))
 {
   final TimelineItem noteItem = mirrorClient.timeline()
                .get(notification.getItemId()).execute();

   final String spokenText = noteItem.getText();

   if ( spokenText.toUpperCase().contains("DONE") 
                  || spokenText.toUpperCase().contains("LIST"))
   {        
      noteItem.setText("Hello Glassware");
          MirrorClient.
              getMirror(credential).timeline().update(notification.getItemId(),  
              noteItem).execute();          
       }
}
 }
```

The update of the timeline card does happen, however I can see both the cards, one w/ "Hello" text and the other w/ "Hello Glassware" text but w/ different timestamp. 
I was expecting to see only the updated timeline card.

Comment: Can you show sample code for how you are doing the update? Typically, the "old" card is replaced completely by the updated card. Having both implies that you have ended up with two IDs.

Comment: There are two java classes, NewUserBootstrapper and NotifyServlet. The NewUserBootstrapper takes care of bootstrapping 
 that includes authentication, inserting contact and inserting subscription. This is the code for inserting a timeline 
 item as part of bootstrapping. 
 
 // Send welcome timeline item
    TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
    timelineItem.setText("Hello");
    timelineItem.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));
    TimelineItem insertedItem = MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, timelineItem);

Comment: Now in the NotifyServlet, after the Service is notified of changes to the timeline as part of "take a note" voice command, 
 the NotifyServlet tries to update the text of the same timeline item:- 
 
 if (notification.getCollection().equals("timeline")) {
      // Get the impacted timeline item
      TimelineItem timelineItem = mirrorClient.timeline().get(notification.getItemId()).execute();
   //Take a note
      if (notification.getUserActions().contains(new UserAction().setType("LAUNCH")))
      {

Comment: final TimelineItem noteItem = mirrorClient.timeline()
     .get(notification.getItemId()).execute();
      
     final String spokenText = noteItem.getText();
      
        if ( spokenText.toUpperCase().contains("DONE") 
          || spokenText.toUpperCase().contains("LIST"))
        {        
         noteItem.setText("Hello Glassware");
         MirrorClient.
         getMirror(credential).timeline().update(notification.getItemId(), noteItem).execute();         
        }
      }
}

Comment: Please update your original post (you should be able to click on the "edit" link under your question) - it is very difficult to read it through comments. Thanks!

Comment: i think there is a limit on length of comments, and that's why I had to break the original post into three.

Comment: You can edit your **original question**. This is a better way to post code than trying to put it in comments.

Comment: Thanks! edited the original post w/ more explanation and code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you're trying to update the wrong card. Although you store the original card as `insertedItem`, you then post the update using `notification`'s ID.

Remember that every action, either done by your Glassware or done by you on Glass, generates a card (and thus an ID). So your voice action generated a card which is stored on your timeline. It is common to either edit this card (to more nicely format it) or to delete the card from the Glassware as part of indicating you've received it and have acted on it.

So what is happening is that you're creating one card (`insertedItem`) from your Glassware, you're issuing a voice command (`notification`, which you then read into `noteItem`) which generates another card, and then updating the second card. It sounds like you really want to update the first card, so you should be updating `insertedItem`.

Comment: I think, your i/ps does makes sense. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I would have to wait till early next week to try the update on timeline items.